# How to detect pinch in gesture vs pinch out gesture?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uipinchgesturerecognizer

Instead of scaling, which I think pinch gesture is usually used for, I am looking to just detect whether the pinch was a pinch in vs pinch out so I can collapse or expand some table sections. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: It is far better to use .velocity, which (obviously!) is positive or negative depending on which way you are going.  The answers below are whacky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, that seems an easy one. The [`UIPinchGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPinchGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class has *only two properties*, `scale` and `velocity`. It seems logical that a negative `scale` would mean an inward pinch, a positive `scale` an outward pinch.

NB: "negative" might be misleading. "Smaller" is `0.0 < scale < 1.0`, "bigger" is `scale > 1.0`.

Comment: hmm pinching out also gives me negative scale? fyi im using pinch dragged from storyboard, with scale set as 1 and delayed end checked and delayed begin unchecked

Comment: Impossible. I doubt that pinching out gives you a negative scale. Please check and describe how you get to this result.

Comment: pinching inward results in a scale that starts at 1.0 and decreases to 0.0, and pinching outward results in a scale that starts and 1.0 and increases from there.

Answer (score 12):

The "scale" property is less than 1 for pinch-in gesture and greater than 1 for pinch-out.
This happens for all pinches with 2 fingers.

What I also observed was that if I pinched in with 5 fingers (which is the shortcut to minimize-to-home), the scale value comes exactly 1.0 - everytime. But this is not supported by any Apple documentation that I'm aware of.

You can experiment what the values are coming by simply putting an NSLog in your pinch handling selector

```
NSLog(@"Scale: %.2f | Velocity: %.2f",pinch.scale,pinch.velocity);
```

Answer (score 3):

You were right to look at the scale property however it switches around 1, not zero.

```
    - (BOOL) pinchWasOutwards:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
    {
        return gestureRecognizer.scale > 1;
    }
```

Comment: Just use .velocity, which is much more KISS.